# SwiftUI @State value doesn't change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem with my code.

```
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: FirebaseModelData
    
    @State var selectionString = ""
    
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    @State var selectedMaster: Master?
    
    var body: some View {
    
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                LocationSelector()
                
                Searchbar()
                
                Text("Фильтр по услугам")
                    .font(.title3)
                
                ServiceTypeSelection(selectionString: $selectionString)
                
                
                VStack {
                    if selectionString != "" {
                        
                        ForEach(0 ..< modelData.masters.count, id: \.self) { master in
                            
                            if modelData.masters[master].serviceTypes.contains(selectionString) {
                                Button {
                                    self.selectedMaster = modelData.masters[master]
                                    isPresented.toggle()
                                } label: {
                                    MasterRow(master: modelData.masters[master])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                        
                    } else {
                        
                        ForEach(0 ..< modelData.masters.count, id: \.self) { master in
                            
                            Button {
                                self.selectedMaster = modelData.masters[master]
                                print(self.selectedMaster)
                                isPresented.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                MasterRow(master: modelData.masters[master])
                            }

                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            MasterView(master: self.selectedMaster!)
                .environment(\.modalMode, self.$isPresented)
        }
            

        
    }
}
```

State value `selectedMaster` is supposed to be changed on button click, but it doesn't and as a result my program crashes. Please help me, I have no idea why this keeps happening.

Additionally, I tried changing the type of `selectedMaster` to Int and pass the required data object as `self.selectedMaster = modelData.masters[master]`, but that didn't work either.

If you have any additional questions, please feel free to ask!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the crash?

Comment: @aheze Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Ok, instead of using 2 properties `isPresented` + `selectedMaster` and `sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)`, use [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) instead.

Comment: @aheze i cannot get rid of `isPresented` because it is used to dismiss the sheet a few screens in

Comment: No problem, instead just set `selectedMaster` to nil

Answer (score 0):

as @aheze suggested, you could try the .sheet(item...), like this:

```
 .sheet(item: $selectedMaster, onDismiss: {isPresented = false}) { theMaster in
     MasterView(master: theMaster)
     .environment(\.modalMode, self.$isPresented) 
 }
```